# Extract text from HTML file

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to extract information from an HTML file using Python. The structure of the file is below.

The text I would like to extract is:

1. ```
   Desc: Identification of a type of document/message by code
            or name. Code preferred.
   ```

and

1. Document name code                        C      an..3

```
<HTML\>
<HEAD\>
<meta http-equiv="Author" content="Claudio Meza, e-Business Team"\>
<meta http-equiv="Description" content="United Nations EDIFACT Directories on the WWW"\>
<meta http-equiv="Keywords" content="EDI, e-commerce, e-business, UN/EDIFACT, UN/CEFACT UN/ECE, ECE, UNECE, CEFACT, XML,  United Nations,  Economic Commission for Europe, United Nations Directories for Administration, Commerce and Transport"\>
<TITLE\>UN/EDIFACT D.22A - Composite Data Element \[C002\]\</TITLE\>
</HEAD\>
<PRE\>\<BODY\>
<table WIDTH="460"border="0" \>\<tr\>\<td align="center" valign="top"\> \<br\>
<font SIZE="+1" COLOR="003399" FACE = "Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, Futura"\>\<b\>
United Nations Directories \<br\>for Electronic Data Interchange for\<br\>
Administration, Commerce and Transport\</font\>\<br\>\<br\>
<img SRC="../pictures/unlog1.gif"WIDTH="142"HEIGHT="116"BORDER="0"\> <br\>
<font SIZE="+5" COLOR="003399" FACE="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, Futura"\>\<b\> UN/EDIFACT\</b\>\</font\>\</p\>
</tr\>\</table\>
<P\>
<P\>

<B\>      Change indicators\</B\>

        a plus sign (+)    for an addition
        an asterisk (*)    for an amendment to structure
        a hash sign (#)    for changes to names
        a vertical bar (|) for changes to text for descriptions,
                           notes and functions
        a minus sign (-)   for a deletion
        an X sign (X)      for marked for deletion

<H3\>       C002 DOCUMENT/MESSAGE NAME\</H3\>

       Desc: Identification of a type of document/message by code
             or name. Code preferred.

010    \<A HREF = "../tred/tred1001.htm"\>1001\</A\>  Document name code                        C      an..3
020    \<A HREF = "../tred/tred1131.htm"\>1131\</A\>  Code list identification code             C      an..17
030    \<A HREF = "../tred/tred3055.htm"\>3055\</A\>  Code list responsible agency code         C      an..3
040    \<A HREF = "../tred/tred1000.htm"\>1000\</A\>  Document name                             C      an..35

<P\>
<P\>
<P\>Composite C002 is used in the following Segments: \<P\>
<P\>    \<A HREF = "../trsd/trsdbgm.htm"\>BGM\</A\>    \<A HREF = "../trsd/trsddms.htm"\>DMS\</A\>    \<A HREF = "../trsd/trsddoc.htm"\>DOC\</A\>
<P\>
<P\>
<center\>\<font face="arial, Helvetica" size="-1" color="#003399"\>\<A href="http://live.unece.org/legal_notice/copyrightnotice.html"\>Copyright United Nations,\</A\> all rights reserved \<br\>  \<br\> \<A href="http://www.unece.org"\> UN Economic Commission for Europe\</A\>\<br\> Palais des Nations, CH-1211 Geneva 10, Switzerland \<br\> Tel: +41-22 917 1366 Fax: +41-22 917 0037  E-mail: \<a href="mailto:TradeMaster@unece.org"\>TradeMaster@unece.org</a\>\<br\> \<BR\>\<a href="http://www.unece.org/trade/untdid/welcome.htm"\>UN/EDIFACT Directories\</a\>\</font\>\</font>\</center\>
</BODY\>
</HTML\>
```

I'm using BeautifulSoup and I can extract the content within the tags. For example: soup.h3. However, I don't know how to extract the text after the tag is closed (/H3).

Answer (score 0):

You could select the [`next_sibling`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling) to get the text after the `<h3>`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''<H3> C002 DOCUMENT/MESSAGE NAME</H3>

   Desc: Identification of a type of document/message by code
         or name. Code preferred.
010 <A HREF = "../tred/tred1001.htm">1001</A>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

soup.h3.next_sibling.strip()
```